# How to skip captive portal to login wifi

Tags: wifimanager

I have a very hard time to remember the account and password, is it possible to skip the log in webpage, and automatically log in to the wifi network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app
```

into

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/No More Captive Network Assistant.app
```

and you're all set. Password entering now goes via your browser of choice and can be stored using 1password or other plugins. Note that if you were already logged in while doing the renaming, it may take some time for your session to expire...

From: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45418/how-to-automatically-login-to-captive-portals-on-os-x